# VBA - Save macro naming workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have code below to save the current workbook and attach today's date to the end of the file name. How would I modify the code so if two copies of the workbook were to be saved on the same day, the first one would save normally as "**Workbook Name, Today's Date.xlsm**" and the second one would save as "**Workbook Name, Today's Date Copy 2.xlsm**" instead of "**Workbook Name, Today's Date, Today's Date.xlsm**" (Attaching the Date twice to the end of the file name, which is what it does now). Same thing if the workbook were to be saved 3,4,5 times a day they should save as Copy 3,4,5,etc...

```
`Sub Save_Workbook()

Const Path = "H:\HR\Cole G\Timehseet Test Path\"
Dim FileName As String
Dim Pos As Long

Pos = InStrRev(ActiveWorkbook.Name, ".") - 1
' If there wasn't a ".", then the file doesn't have an extension and Pos = -1
If Pos < 0 Then Pos = Len(ActiveWorkbook.Name)

' Now put everything together, including the file extension...
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Path & Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, Pos) & Format    (Now, "d-mm-yyyy") & Mid(ActiveWorkbook.Name, Pos + 1)

End Sub`
```

Comment: You'd have to read the file save location to ensure another file with that name does not already exist.  if it does, read the file name and duplication & "Copy" & count in folder +1

Comment: @Cyril Ahh okay, ill give that a go! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could try a recursive approach like so (not tested):

```
Sub CreateCopyFile(ByVal oldFileName As String, Optional ByVal copyNo As Long = 1)
    If FileLen(oldFileName & " Copy (" & copyNo & ")") Then
        CreateCopyFile(oldFileName, copyNo + 1)
    Else
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs oldFileName & " Copy (" & copyNo & ")"
    End If
End Sub
```

Then change your code to the following:

```
Dim potentialFileName As String    
potentialFileName = Path & Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, Pos) & Format(Now, "d-mm-yyyy") & Mid(ActiveWorkbook.Name, Pos + 1)

If FileLen(potentialFileName) Then
    CreateCopyFile(potentialFileName)
Else
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs potentialFileName
End If

'// rest of code here....
```

There used to be a cleaner way of doing this using a command prompt, however in recent years it seems that Windows no longer allows the use of it via VBA without changing security settings (which I do not advise...)

Answer (score 0):

```
If Dir(Path & Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, Pos) & Format    (Now, "d-mm-yyyy") & Mid(ActiveWorkbook.Name, Pos + 1)) <> "" Then
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Path & Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, Pos) & copy 2 & Mid(ActiveWorkbook.Name, Pos + 1)
Else
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Path & Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, Pos) & Format    (Now, "d-mm-yyyy") & Mid(ActiveWorkbook.Name, Pos + 1)
```

use this to save your file

Comment: This removes the date and replaces it with Copy 2